# Why does pivoting code bring failure to my LU decomposition?

Tags: matlab

Before speaking, I am writing this with a translator, not an English speaker. Therefore, I ask for your understanding even if my English is terrible.

After learning how to write a non-pivoting LU-decomposition code, I decided to try to write a LU-decomposition code that uses pivoting for homework.
Since my non-pivoting code went well as below, so I thought it would be easy to make a pivoting LU-decomposition code.

But it went bad, really bad...

```
% non-pivoting code
function x = mylu_np(A)
    [m,~] = size(A);
    L = eye(m); U = A(:,:);
    for i = 1:m-1
        for j = i+1:m
            L(j,i) = U(j,i)/U(i,i);
            U(j,i) = 0;
            U(j,i+1:m) = U(j,i+1:m) - L(j,i)*U(i,i+1:m);
        end
    end
    x = [L U];
end
```

My code is following. Please let me know where this code fails. I don't know why such a serious failure occurs even though I only put in the pivot part.

```
function x = mylu_pp(A)
    [m,~] = size(A);
    P = eye(m); L = eye(m); U = A(:,:);
    for i = 1:m-1
        for j = i+1:m
            if abs(U(i,i)) < abs(U(j,i))
                U([i j],:) = U([j i],:);
                P([i j],:) = P([j i],:);
            end
        end
        for j = i+1:m
            L(j,i) = U(j,i)/U(i,i);
            U(j,i) = 0;
            U(j,i+1:m) = U(j,i+1:m) - L(j,i)*U(i,i+1:m);
        end
    end
    x = [P L U];
end
```

I tested with 4*4 matrix A like this

```
A = [0.0001 -5.0300 5.8090 7.8320;
    2.2660 1.9950 1.2120 8.0080;
    8.8500 5.6810 4.5520 1.3020;
    6.7750 -2.2530 2.9080 3.9700];
W = mylu_pp(A)
P = W(1:4,1:4); L = W(1:4,5:8); U = W(1:4,9:12);
P*A - L*U
```

and the answer comes like this. Really bad.

```
ans = [0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000;
    6.7749 4.3489 3.4847 0.9967;
    -2.2659 -7.0250 -1.6521 2.1754
    -4.5090 2.6761 -1.8326 -3.1721]
```

Tell me which part is the problem. All kinds of help are welcome. I will thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is related to the matrix `L`.

When swapping rows `i` and `j` in matrix `U`, we also have to swap the elements in the rows `i` and `j` of matrix `L`, but only the elements that were updated earlier (not the entire rows):

```
if i > 1
    L([i j], 1:i-1) = L([j i], 1:i-1);
end
```

---

The way I am thinking about it is equivalent to renaming the variables in the equation system.
I am not a mathematician, and my explanation is not going to be very good...

Assume we have the equation system: `A*v = b`.
Using LU decomposition we are solving the equation as: `L*U*v = b`.

Assume:

```
    [x
v =  y
     z
     w]
```

After swapping two rows in matrix `U`, we have to keep equivalence to the original equation system.
The way of keep equivalence is renaming the elements in `v`.

When swapping row 2 with row 4, we may swap the names of `y` and `w`, and get new `v`:

```
     [x
v0 =  w
      z
      y]
```

---

The equivalence to names swapping is:

- Swapping the two rows in matrix `U`.
- Swapping the two rows in matrix `P`.
  `P*A` reorder the rows of `A` to the new "swapped order".
- We also have to swap the elements in the rows of matrix `L`, but only the elements that were updated earlier (not the entire row).
  Swapping the relevant elements in rows 2 and 4 of `L` follows the equivalence of swapping the names of `y` and `w`.

---

Code sample:

```
A = [0.0001 -5.0300 5.8090 7.8320;
     2.2660  1.9950 1.2120 8.0080;
     8.8500  5.6810 4.5520 1.3020;
     6.7750 -2.2530 2.9080 3.9700];

[P, L, U] = mylu_pp(A);
P*A - L*U

function [P, L, U] = mylu_pp(A)
    m = size(A, 1);
    P = eye(m); L = eye(m); U = A;
    for i = 1:m-1
        for j = i+1:m
            if abs(U(i,i)) < abs(U(j,i))
                U([i j],:) = U([j i],:);
                P([i j],:) = P([j i],:);
                
                if i > 1
                    % Swap the relevant elements "1:i-1" in the row of matrix L (only the elements that were updated until now).
                    L([i j], 1:i-1) = L([j i], 1:i-1);
                end
            end
        end
        for j = i+1:m
            L(j,i) = U(j,i)/U(i,i);
            U(j,i) = 0;
            U(j,i+1:m) = U(j,i+1:m) - L(j,i)*U(i,i+1:m);
        end
    end
    %x = [P L U];
end
```

---

Output `P*A - L*U`:

```
ans =

     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
```